# Time comparison logic in Postgresql not working

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, comparison, plpgsql

I've been writing code for postgresql for about two weeks now, and its my first time playing in a (real) database, having swapped from access 2003 (oh no), which was too restrictive and slow to process the data.

I've written a function that looks through the logs in another database to tell how long it takes to serve a customer.  The problem is, I'm trying to make it *stop* looking and act as if the serving ended if there is no action in the database for 3 minutes.  There is a transaction that is a hard stop, and I flag that with "E", and if the username is different, the serving has ended.  For hard stop and the username change, the code works fine.  For the time logic, it does not.

```
CREATE FUNCTION rspcalc() RETURNS VOID
language plpgsql as $$
<<fn>>
DECLARE

_reportdata public.transactional_flag%ROWTYPE;
_currentusername varchar(255);
_intransaction boolean;
_nextslice time;
_endtime timestamp;
_currenttime timestamp;

BEGIN

_currentusername = 'XXXX';
_intransaction = false;

FOR _reportdata IN
    SELECT * FROM transactional_flag
        ORDER BY transactional_username, transactional_actiontime DESC LOOP

    --If username currently in use is not the username on the row, end the transaction measure

    IF NOT (_currentusername = _reportdata.transactional_username) THEN

        IF _intransaction THEN
        INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username) 
            VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername);
        END IF;

        _intransaction = FALSE;
        _currentusername = _reportdata.transactional_username;
        _nextslice = '00:00:00'::time;

    END IF;

    CASE _reportdata.transactional_type

    --O represents an output - the assumption is if they do happen, they happen within 5 secounds of the end of a transaction

        WHEN 'O' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

                IF _reportdata.transactional_actiontime > (_currenttime + _nextslice) THEN

                INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username) 
                    VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername);

                _intransaction = FALSE;
                _nextslice = '00:00:05'::time;
                ELSE

                _currenttime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                _nextslice = '00:03:00'::time;

                END IF;

            ELSE

                _currenttime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                _nextslice = '00:00:05'::time;

            END IF;

    --E represents the end of a transaction

        WHEN 'E' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

                INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username) 
                    VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername);

                _intransaction = true;
                _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                _currenttime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                _nextslice = '00:03:00'::time;

            ELSE

                IF _reportdata.transactional_actiontime > (_currenttime + _nextslice) THEN

                _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;

                END IF;

            _currenttime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
            _nextslice = '00:03:00'::time;
            _intransaction = true;

            END IF;

    --N represents any user use of the system, except an end
    --S represents a document creation

        WHEN 'N', 'S' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

                IF _reportdata.transactional_actiontime > (_currenttime + _nextslice) THEN

                INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username) 
                    VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername);

                _intransaction = FALSE;
                _nextslice = '00:00:00'::time;

                ELSE
                _currenttime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                _nextslice = '00:03:00'::time;
                END IF;

            ELSE

            _nextslice = '00:00:00'::time;

            END IF;

        ELSE
        --PANIC

    END CASE;

END LOOP;

END $$;
```

I have RTFM so hard (but probably not hard enough).  I have tested much of the code piece by piece, but I'm at a loose end.

I taught myself to code in VB6 only recently, so any advice you can give on any aspect of the code will be appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE transactional_flag
(
  transactional_rowid bigserial NOT NULL,
  transactional_actiontime timestamp without time zone,
  transactional_systemstring character varying(3),
  transactional_username character varying(255),
  transactional_type character varying(1),
  CONSTRAINT transactional_flag_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transactional_rowid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX transactional_index
  ON transactional_flag
  USING btree
  (transactional_username COLLATE pg_catalog."default", transactional_actiontime DESC);

CREATE TABLE transactional_report
(
  transactional_rowid bigserial NOT NULL,
  transactional_endtime timestamp without time zone,
  transactional_starttime timestamp without time zone,
  transactional_username character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT transactional_report_pkey PRIMARY KEY (transactional_rowid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


INSERT INTO transactional_report
    ("transactional_rowid", "transactional_endtime", "transactional_starttime", "transactional_username")
VALUES
    (1004053,'2014-09-19 01:21:09','2014-09-15 01:06:07','EXSP1049'),
    (1004054,'2014-09-15 01:06:06','2014-09-12 06:30:49','EXSP1049')
;

INSERT INTO transactional_flag
    ("transactional_rowid", "transactional_actiontime", "transactional_systemstring", "transactional_username", "transactional_type")
VALUES
    (16543226, '2014-09-19 01:21:22', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
    (16543163, '2014-09-19 01:21:10', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
    (16543153, '2014-09-19 01:21:09', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
    (16820614, '2014-09-19 01:21:09', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'E'),
    (16543135, '2014-09-19 01:21:03', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16543012, '2014-09-19 01:20:36', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16543007, '2014-09-19 01:20:35', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542996, '2014-09-19 01:20:34', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542997, '2014-09-19 01:20:34', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542908, '2014-09-19 01:20:09', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542864, '2014-09-19 01:19:58', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542858, '2014-09-19 01:19:56', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542852, '2014-09-19 01:19:54', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542693, '2014-09-19 01:19:17', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542605, '2014-09-19 01:18:53', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542600, '2014-09-19 01:18:52', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542498, '2014-09-19 01:18:24', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542494, '2014-09-19 01:18:22', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542424, '2014-09-19 01:18:13', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16542183, '2014-09-19 01:17:43', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15903153, '2014-09-15 01:06:07', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15903146, '2014-09-15 01:06:06', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16797265, '2014-09-15 01:06:06', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'E'),
(15903060, '2014-09-15 01:05:48', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15903046, '2014-09-15 01:05:45', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15902188, '2014-09-15 01:03:18', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15902173, '2014-09-15 01:03:14', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15900149, '2014-09-15 00:57:18', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15899930, '2014-09-15 00:56:36', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15899922, '2014-09-15 00:56:34', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15899430, '2014-09-15 00:54:55', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15899406, '2014-09-15 00:54:51', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15899053, '2014-09-15 00:53:16', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15899042, '2014-09-15 00:53:12', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898854, '2014-09-15 00:52:17', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898698, '2014-09-15 00:51:32', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898683, '2014-09-15 00:51:29', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898682, '2014-09-15 00:51:28', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898645, '2014-09-15 00:51:21', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898637, '2014-09-15 00:51:19', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898605, '2014-09-15 00:51:11', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15898046, '2014-09-15 00:49:23', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897966, '2014-09-15 00:49:10', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897916, '2014-09-15 00:49:00', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897894, '2014-09-15 00:48:54', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897620, '2014-09-15 00:48:02', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897556, '2014-09-15 00:47:49', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897528, '2014-09-15 00:47:44', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897324, '2014-09-15 00:47:00', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15897300, '2014-09-15 00:46:55', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15892174, '2014-09-15 00:28:37', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15886571, '2014-09-15 00:10:07', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15886455, '2014-09-15 00:09:47', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15886286, '2014-09-15 00:09:22', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15859397, '2014-09-12 06:30:49', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(16795869, '2014-09-12 06:30:49', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'E'),
(15859389, '2014-09-12 06:30:48', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15859375, '2014-09-12 06:30:46', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15859247, '2014-09-12 06:30:18', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N'),
(15859228, '2014-09-12 06:30:15', 'PEA', 'EXSP1049', 'N')
;
```

Comment: I think you might need to show the actual data that corresponds to the code, otherwise it's rather hard to tell what's going on. Can you show some sample data? http://sqlfiddle.com/ . I also don't really understand what you're trying to achive with a void procedure here.

Comment: I don't have an OpenID so i just added the schema here.  Both transactional_endtime's are correct, but the start times should be 2014-09-19 01:17:43 and 2014-09-15 01:03:14 respectively.

Comment: Also to be honest I don't know why I selected a void procedure.  I just did this because it allowed me to execute code.  I'm not too confident or knowledgeable about what other options there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this works, but I restructured the code and changed the type of _nextslice to a timestamp.  I also added some more functionality surrounding sales orders.

```
CREATE FUNCTION rspcalc() RETURNS VOID 
language plpgsql as $$
<<fn>>
DECLARE

_reportdata public.transactional_flag%ROWTYPE;
_currentusername varchar(255);
_currentSOtype varchar(4);
_intransaction boolean;
_nextslice timestamp;
_endtime timestamp;
_currenttime timestamp;

BEGIN

_currentusername = 'XXXX';
_intransaction = false;
_currentSOtype = '';

FOR _reportdata IN
    SELECT * FROM transactional_flag
        ORDER BY transactional_username, transactional_actiontime DESC LOOP

    --If username currently in use is not the username on the row, end the transaction measure

    IF NOT (_currentusername = _reportdata.transactional_username) THEN

        IF _intransaction THEN
        INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username, transactional_salesordertype) 
            VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername, _currentSOtype);
        END IF;

        _intransaction = FALSE;
        _currentusername = _reportdata.transactional_username;
        _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
        _currentSOtype = '';

    END IF;

    --If this row's actiontime is before the acceptable backwards-stretching _nextslice, end the transaction

    IF _intransaction AND (_reportdata.transactional_actiontime < _nextslice) THEN

    INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username, transactional_salesordertype) 
        VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername, _currentSOtype);

    _intransaction = FALSE;
    _currentSOtype = '';

    END IF;

    CASE _reportdata.transactional_type

    --N represents any CIC0 or VA01 transaction in STAD

        WHEN 'N' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

            _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime - '00:03:00'::time;

            ELSE

            _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;

            END IF;
    --S represents a document creation in VBAK

        WHEN 'S' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

            _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime - '00:03:00'::time;
            _currentSOtype = _reportdata.transactional_salesordertype;

            ELSE

            _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;

            END IF;

    --O represents an output in NAST

        WHEN 'O' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

            _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime - '00:03:00'::time;

            ELSE

            _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime - '00:00:05'::time;
            _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;

            END IF;

    --E represents a VA - U - 3000 in STAD - the end of a transaction

        WHEN 'E' THEN

            IF _intransaction THEN

                INSERT INTO transactional_report (transactional_endtime, transactional_starttime, transactional_username, transactional_salesordertype) 
                    VALUES (_endtime, _currenttime, _currentusername, _currentSOtype);

                _currentSOtype = '';

                _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;

            ELSE
                IF _endtime > (_reportdata.transactional_actiontime + '00:00:05'::time) THEN
                    _endtime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;
                END IF;

            END IF;

        _nextslice = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime - '00:03:00'::time;
        _intransaction = TRUE;

        ELSE
        --PANIC

    END CASE;

_currenttime = _reportdata.transactional_actiontime;

END LOOP;

END $$;
```